# Correspondence between real forms and real structures on complex Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I asked this in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293689/real-form-and-real-structure-on-a-complex-lie-group), but without success, so I hope, it will be suitable here.

E.B.Vinberg and A.L.Onishchik in their [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=TV7sCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=real%20form%20and%20real%20structure&source=bl&ots=Z1jxruqogp&sig=nmKix-DFWTL-52qBbob2nw76PU4&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=MZ5eVb7dKsT-ygOOpIGAAw&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=real%20form%20and%20real%20structure&f=false) give the following two definitions.

1. For a complex Lie group $G$ its real Lie subgroup $H$ is called a *real form* of $G$, if

   a) the Lie algebra $L(H)$ of $H$ is a real form of the Lie algebra
   $L(G)$ of $G$ (this means that $L(G)$ is a complexification of $L(H)$), and

   b) $H$ has a non-empty intersection with each connected component of $G$
2. A (continuous) homomorphism $S:G\to G$ (of a complex Lie group $G$) is called a *real structure* on $G$, if

   a) $S(S(g))=g$, for $g\in G$, and

   b) the corresponding mapping of the Lie algebra $d S:L(G)\to L(G)$ is a real structure (another term: an involution) on $L(G)$.

It is known that on a *connected complex Lie group* (or on an *irreducible algebraic group*) $G$ for each real structure $S:G\to G$ the subgroup of stable elements
$$
H=\{g\in G:\ Sg=g\}
$$
is a real form on $G$, and the Lie algebra $L(H)$ coincides with the set of stable elements for $dS$:
$$
L(H)=\{x\in L(G):\ dS(x)=x\}.
$$

My question:

> Is this a one-to-one correspondence between real forms and real structures (for a reasonable class of groups)?

In particular,

> if $H$ is a real form of a complex a Lie group $G$, does there always exist a real structure $S:G\to G$ such that $H$ is the subgroup of stable elements for $S$ in $G$, and $L(H)$ is the subspace of stable elements for $dS$ in $L(G)$?

This is strange, I can't find a reference, even for the case, when

> $H$ is a compact real Lie group, and $G$ is its complexification.

(Actually, that would be enough for me.)

I would be grateful for anybody's help.

Comment: On the Lie algebra level, yes. On the Lie group level, if $G$ is simply connected. See Ch III, Section 6 (p 178 ff) of Helgason: Differential Geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces.

Comment: Does this give an answer in the case, when $K$ is a compact real Lie group and $G$ is its complexification?

Comment: I don't understand "i.e." as the first 2 questions are not equivalent: in the first question you ask if the map from a certain set of involutions on $G$ to a certain set (which one?) of subsets of $G$ is a bijection (or an injection, if by definition the target set is by definition the image). In the purportedly equivalent second question, you map to a set of isomorphism classes, and anyway the second question is a surjectivity question.

Comment: @YCor: Pardon, I corrected the text in MSE (and here also).

Comment: I guess you mean that $dS$ is an involutive $\mathbf{C}$-skew-linear Lie algebra automorphism. Also in your definition both $GL_n(\mathbf{R})$ and $GL_n^+(\mathbf{R})$ are real forms on $GL_n(\mathbf{C})$, but only the first can be obtained as the fixed point of a skew-linear involution.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, I thought the same, an involutive anti-linear Lie algebra automorphism. So this is not a one-to-one correspondence?... I think, at least for reductive groups (i.e. for complexifications of compact real Lie groups) this must be so... That's true?

Comment: 1. If $G$ is a complex Lie group, and $S\colon G\to G$ is an *anti-holomorphic* involutive (i.e., $S^2=1$) automorphism, then the subgroup of fixed points $G^S$ of $S$ in $G$ is the desired real Lie group (the real form corresponding to the real structure $S$).

Comment: 2. Conversely, if $G_0$ is a *compact* Lie group, then it is a *real algebraic group*, i.e., it is the set of *real zeros* in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ of a finite set polynomials with real coefficients in the $n^2$ matrix elements $g_{i,j}$.  Let $G$ denote the complex Lie group of *complex* zeros of these polynomials in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, it has a canonical real structure $S\colon  g\mapsto \bar g$ (the complex conjugation on the matix elements). This is the desired complexification of a real algebraic group $G_0$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, excuse me, I did not understand, for which class of groups this is a one-to-one correspondence? And is this a folklore, or there exist references?

Comment: This is a bijection between the isomorphism classes of: (A) affine real algebraic groups $G_0$ (resp. affine real varieties) and (B) affine complex algebraic groups $G$ (resp. varieties) endowed with a anti-holomorphic involutive automorphism $S$. The map from (A) to (B): $G_0\mapsto G_0\times_R C$. The map from (B) to (A): you take the ring ($\mathbb{C}$-algebra) of regular functions $R=\mathbb{C}[G]$ on $G$, consider the ring ($\mathbb{R}$-algebra) of $S$-invariants $R^S$, and set $G_0={\rm Spec}\,R^S$.

Comment: This is called "Galois descent", a reference is Serre's book "Algebraic Groups and Class Fields", Ch. V-20, Prop. 12 (page 142 of Russian edition). This is a reference for any Galois extension $k_1/k$. You should take $k=\mathbb{R}$, $k_1=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Serre proves the existence of  descent  (the map from (B) to (A) ) also for *quasi-projective* varieties (not necessarily affine) and for all algebraic groups (not necessarily affine), see Corollary 2 in Serre's book.  For not quasi-projective varieties descent is not always possible, even for $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Explanation: by an anti-holomorphic map I mean a semi-algebraic anti-holomorphic map, i.e., given by polynomials in $\bar g_{i,j}$.

Comment: It can indeed be confusing to sort things out on the purely analytic side (where certain ideas from the algebraic theory break down). Look at D.2 and especially D.3 (which are all about the link between compact Lie groups and reductive complex Lie groups) in Appendix D of the article on reductive group schemes in http://smf4.emath.fr/en/Publications/PanoramasSyntheses/2014/42-43/html/smf_pano-synth_42-43.php